# is 'Extending U-SQL scripts with R code in Visual Studio' available?

Tags: r, visual-studio, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Can I use R scripts in USQL while working on local microsoft studio? All documents that i can find are related to Azure execution only.-

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-r-extensions.md

Till last year, this was not done. Any Idea if we can use R scripts in Visual Studio( USQL project) now ?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/938d423f-b163-4273-87af-cc0af7b301ec/r-in-adla-script?forum=AzureDataLake

Comment: Check here for a step-by-step:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333878/install-azure-u-sql-extensions-to-run-r-python-scripts-locally/52333879#52333879

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please see [Enabling U-SQL Advanced Analytics for Local Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2017/02/20/enabling-u-sql-advanced-analytics-for-local-execution/).